# How to calculate wind force (air resistance) on a rectangular object?

Tags: drag

Let's say you're driving down the road at 70mph (112 kph).  If you hold a sign out of your window that's 20x20 cm square, how much force will be applied to the sign by the relative wind?

Comment: Use the [drag equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation).

Comment: @lemon, Hi, thanks for that.  I calculated the force to be about 20 newtons, is that about right?  I'm not sure because I don't know what the units are in that formula.

Comment: I get 25.2 Newtons.